# Home network configuration issue

Tags: networking, router

I need help with following problem with my network:

I bought mesh WIFI system from TP-Link (Deco x20). Devices have 2 Ethernet ports per device. I need to connect first room to internet and second to internet and IPTV. Each room are connected to staircase (where are router) by one network cable.

I made a picture that shows how I wish to have it finally. Configuration like on screen is correct and will work? or should I buy and place router behind switch and "RT" with 2x ports make as AP?

[image: Home network]

Answer (score 1):

It's partly correct. There is no connectivity between the router and the "ISP" (I assume ISP is the modem to your ISP with whatever connection you use, DSL, fiber, etc.): both "connections" (or strictly speaking both switch ports) between the router and switch are tagged, but the "connection" to the "ISP" is untagged, so there will be no connection between "ISP" and router.

Note: I have no idea what an IPTV modem is, so I'm not sure about the IPTV tags, but it looks ok